# Efficient rendering of animated urban scene (using LiDAR point cloud)

Tags: memory-management

I have a colourized aerial laser scan of a municipality that I would like to render in an animation. Below is an example I created for a small subsection:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WAoLJ6H1Qc0fIBdWPg9QvwVTKOTSEMSv/view?usp=sharing

As you can see, the trees and structures are represented by a cloud of points (within Blender, they are imported as equilateral triangles).

The entire dataset is many hundreds of millions of these points, but as the camera pans over the municipality, only a small section will ever be on camera at a time. The entire town is never displayed at once, although I would like the panning camera to sweep over the area seemlessly.

Is there an efficient way of doing this? I'm not sure I can even load the entire dataset into Blender at once. Is there any way to work with "tiles" of data, for instance?

Thanks!